# Подскажите примеры создания приложения для ментальных карт или блок-схем под reactjs или JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть различные онлайн приложения для создания ментальных карт, блок-схем и тому подобного. Уже длительное время пытаюсь найти уроки по созданию хотя бы простейшей версии подобных приложений. Но из-за того что я видимо не могу правильно сформулировать поисковый запрос, я не смог найти ни одного примера создания.

Желательно примеры на reactjs, но можно и на javaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбирайте, есть разные варианты от простых до сложных:

https://github.com/learn-anything/learn-anything

https://github.com/learn-anything/react-mindmap

https://github.com/metamaps/metamaps